# Fold expressions with operator >>

Tags: c++, clang, variadic-templates, compiler-bug, fold-expression

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... types> void writeall(const types & ... items)
{
    (std :: cout << ... << items);
}

template <typename... types> void readall(types & ... items)
{
    (std :: cin >> ... >> items);
}

int main()
{
    writeall(1, 2, 3, 4);
    std :: cout << std :: endl;

    int a, b, c, d;
    readall(a, b, c, d);
}
```

In `writeall`, I use fold expressions to feed into `std :: cout` a parameter pack. Everything works perfectly, and I get `1234` printed out to screen.

In `readall`, I do exactly the same, expecting to read from `std :: cin` a parameter pack. However, I get

```
error: expected ')'
(std :: cin >> ... >> items);
```

What am I doing wrong? One would expect things to work exactly the same, I just replaced operator `<<` with operator `>>`.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the two expressions `(std :: cout << ... << items);` and `(std :: cin >> ... >> items);` should behave more or less identically...? What am I missing?

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32563

Comment: Uh. I see. Nasty. Has this been fixed in any newer version of Clang? I am using 5.0.1.

Comment: @MatteoMonti Fixed in Clang HEAD 7.0 https://wandbox.org/permlink/aedqC0BdJbYa3lJX

Comment: I see exactly the same two errors for << and >> operator.

Comment: It compiles with [GCC 7.3](https://godbolt.org/g/TGrCB9)

Answer (score 1):

As @T.C. answered, this is a bug in clang.  It [has been fixed](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32563).  There was what appeared to be a typo that made `>` and `>>` not work right in fold expressions.